# выдаёт ошибку после старта бота телеграмм

Tags: бот

```
import config
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


client = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(client)

@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def get_text(message):
    if  message.text.lower() == '/start':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, '')
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет,  {message.from_user.first_name} Я первый бот в телеге, созданный криворуким начинающим программистом\nНапиши -help для помощи в моих командах\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\nЕсли я внезапно перестану отвечать, то не волнуйся - я не сломался, просто нахожусь на стадии"РАЗРАБОТКИ" и переодически обновляюсь \n @HeyBlsvbot - предлагать идеи и сообщать о найденных багах')

@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
    if "даун" in message.text:
        await message.delete()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
    client.polling(none_stop=True, interval = 0)
```

Ошибка - **'Bot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'**

Comment: Выглядит, будто вы скопипастили 2 куска кода, написанные с использованием двух совершенно разных библиотек и явили на свет чудовище Франкенштейна... Слава богу оно не ожило. Лучше определитесь с используемой библиотекой и перепишите, пожалуйста, это все с нуля самостоятельно, руками, благо, тут совсем не много, разбирая каждую строчку с помощью документации, должно стать лучше:)

Comment: да, так и есть, я из двух ботов, разных по выполнению своих задач, решил сделать одного.

Comment: помогите пожалуйста вот с этим вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1296541/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python