# как добавить список слов боту телеграм на python

Tags: aiogram, бот, telegram

Заранее извиняюсь за глупые вопросы)

```
import config
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


client = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
mat = ('слово')
dp = Dispatcher(client)

@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
    if mat in message.text:
        await message.delete()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Мне нужно добавить список слов, при наличии которых, бот будет удалять сообщение отправителя.
К примеру я написал `mat = ('слово')`, но не знаю как добавить ещё слова, помогите мне пожалуйста;)

Comment: используйте список `['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']` https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571635/12785139

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/7571635/12785139 – Violet можно с вами связаться в соц сетях, мне нужна помощь

Comment: Напишите свой телеграмм

Comment: https://t.me/HeyBlBotMod